# Are Starter Deck Yugi Reloaded and Starter Deck Kaiba Reloaded balanced against each other?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm a fan of the original *Yu-Gi-Oh!* anime, but don't want to spend the money to buy lots of booster packs. I recently found that there are two new Starter Decks featuring the archrivals from the original series:

- [Starter Deck Yugi Reloaded](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Starter_Deck:_Yugi_Reloaded)
- [Starter Deck Kaiba Reloaded](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Starter_Deck:_Kaiba_Reloaded)

The idea of just buying two off the shelf decks for characters of the original series and playing them against each other appeals to me. Are these two Starter Decks balanced against each other so that each deck will win close to 50% of the time against the other? Or is one much more likely to win in a duel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starter decks are well, starter decks.  I have both of the decks mentioned.  They play OK, and are fairly balanced against each other.  However, they brick often and have a hard time getting started.  They are starter decks, and are a good introduction to the game.  They do not play like a good competitive deck.  If you want to check out the game, it is a good investment.  However, you will find the game is more enjoyable by collecting additional cards.

Also, please note, there is at least one tournament forbidden card, and several restricted cards in those sets.